Issues working with the ESP rmt ir_nec_transceiver
I have an application already working which runs on an Arduino Node MCU board which sends IR commands to an IR transmitter. There is good library support ( IRremoteESP8266 ) for to achieve this on the Arduino.
https://github.com/crankyoldgit/IRremoteESP8266/blob/master/src/ir_EliteScreens.cpp .
Basically there are just three IR Hex commands which I must be able to send :
0xFEA3387 (STOP)
0xFDA2256 (UP)
0xFBA1136 (DOWN)
Example:
irsend.sendElitescreens(0xFEA3387);


Now I wish to develop a similar application for an ESP32-C6-DevKitM-1 development board.
I am trying to understand and adapt the IR_NEC_TRANSCEIVER example which is part of the ESP-IDF repository :
https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/peripherals/rmt/ir_nec_transceiver
There is a function called as follows in the example, with just random address and command values:
const ir_nec_scan_code_t scan_code = {
        .address = 0x0440,
        .command = 0x3003,
};

rmt_transmit(tx_channel, nec_encoder, &scan_code, sizeof(scan_code), &transmit_config);

I am struggling to figure out how to simply send a hex command like from the Arduino application such as 0xFDA2256.
I tried the following:
uint64_t payload = 0xFDA2256;

rmt_transmit(tx_channel, nec_encoder, &payload, sizeof(payload), &transmit_config);

There is an IRrecvDump application which runs on an Arduino which reads Infrared messages and dumps all the information.
https://github.com/crankyoldgit/IRremoteESP8266/blob/master/examples/IRrecvDump/IRrecvDump.ino
I don't understand how I end up with the data, code and address as below. My aim here is to have the data and code as 0xFDA2256 . I would appreciate any help or clarity with this. Thanks.
Timestamp : 000104.243
Library   : v2.8.6

Protocol  : NEC_LIKE
Code      : 0x6A445BF0 (32 Bits)
uint16_t rawData[67] = {8992, 4508,  544, 562,  566, 1716,  522, 1716,  546, 560,  544, 1716,  546, 558,  542, 1720,  544, 560,  542, 588,  546, 1714,  540, 566,  544, 562,  568, 560,  544, 1716,  546, 558,  544, 586,  546, 558,  542, 1744,  522, 558,  542, 1744,  520, 1714,  542, 566,  544, 1714,  548, 1716,  520, 1714,  546, 1716,  522, 1714,  548, 1714,  544, 558,  572, 558,  580, 526,  544, 584,  520};  // NEC_LIKE 6A445BF0
uint32_t address = 0x2256;
uint32_t command = 0x0;
uint64_t data = 0x6A445BF0;


Does this answer your question? ESP-IDF - How to use rmt_transmit for sending IR data
